# geb filtering link by its content

Tags: groovy, automation, geb

I have a page with bunch of hyperlinks. I want geb browser automation suite to filter a specific link by its display value. I could do as below and it works.

```
        def links = $("a")
        def a =[]
        links.each {
            if (it.text() == "blah blah blah....") {
                a.add(it)
            }
        }
        //do something with a
```

Is there a better way of doing this. Perhaps filter(). But I cant seem to get it working.

Thanks
Sajith

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select by text in Geb:

```
$("a", text: "blah blah blah...")
```

If you want to reuse a selector and filter by text then you can indeed use `filter()`:

```
def links = $("a")
def linksWithText = a.filter(text: "blah blah blah...")
```

Comment: What if the text is dynamic so you only want to test if a substring is in the text?